# Points within a rectangle

Tags: python, function, class, if-statement, rectangles

I have a point and rectangle class. I am trying to write a function in the rectangle class that will check if the point is in the rectangle, but I am getting syntax errors.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
       self.x = x
       self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
       return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

class Rectangle(object):
   def __init__(self, posn, w, h):
      self.corner = posn
      self.width = w
      self.height = h

   def __str__(self):
      return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.corner, self.width, self.height)
   def contains(self):
      if self.x < self.width and self.y < self.height:
         return True
      else:
         return False
```

Comment: post the errors... it will help :)

Comment: one thing that's obvious: `if self.x < self.width and self.y < self.height:`... the Rectangle class does not define the `x` and `y` attributes. Also, `contains()` takes no argument... what is it testing against?

Comment: r = Rectangle(Point(0, 0), 10, 5)
r.contains(Point(0, 0)) should return True
r.contains(Point(3, 3)) should return True
r.contains(Point(3, 7)) should return False

Comment: Will all of your rectangles have sides that are parallel to the x and y axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `contains` method doesn't take a point as an argument, only `self` (which is the rectangle you're calling the method on). You need to add a parameter, then use it when looking up the point's info.

You probably also need to check all boundaries of the rectangle, so there will be four comparisons. You can simplify the comparisons a bit by using Python's operator chaining (`a < b < c` is equivalent to `a < b and b < c`).

Furthermore, there's no need for `if` statements, you can just return the Boolean result of your comparisons directly.

Here's code that I think should work for you, though I may not have correctly guessed at how you are treating the `corner` value:

```
def contains(self, point):
    return (self.corner.x <= point.x <= self.corner.x + self.width and
            self.corner.y <= point.y <= self.corner.y + self.height)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be consistent with your indentation. You have mixed four, three, and two space indentations in your code. [Here's a link to PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the standard style guide most people follow.

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __str__(self):
        return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, posn, w, h):
        self.corner = posn
        self.width = w
        self.height = h

    def __str__(self):
        return "({0},{1},{2})".format(self.corner, self.width, self.height)

    def contains(self):
        if self.x < self.width and self.y < self.height:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```